# Prevent draggable items to overlap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, while-loop

I'm developing a game in React-native. I have an array of objects (`tile`) that are absolutely positioned on render. The snap points are a grid of 2 rows with 16 columns.

`Width`, `height` and `coordinates` are a property of the object. Occasionally my objects overlap each other on drag release. I don't know exactly how it happens but I'm assuming it happens when I drag an item from the second row (`y > 0`) to the first row (`y === 0`) initially. I've been stuck on it for a while now and cannot figure it out.

The below is my function to handle the `chain reaction`. When a tile is moved to an occupied snap point, all other tiles in the chain should be moved either to the left / right and to the beginning / end of a row.

See screen recording: [video](https://i.imgur.com/SZfU4b5.mp4)

```
  // Function to handle chain reaction
  const handleChainReaction = (newTiles, movedTile) => {
    let tilesToCheck = [movedTile];

    while (tilesToCheck.length > 0) {
      let currentTile = tilesToCheck.shift();

      let occupiedIndex;
      do {
        occupiedIndex = newTiles.findIndex(
          (t) =>
            t.x === currentTile.x &&
            t.y === currentTile.y &&
            t.key !== currentTile.key
        );

        if (occupiedIndex !== -1) {
          let displacedTile = { ...newTiles[occupiedIndex] };
          displacedTile.x += TILE_WIDTH; // Move the tile to the right

          // Check for horizontal boundary
          if (displacedTile.x >= CONTAINER_WIDTH) {
            displacedTile.x = 0;
            displacedTile.y += TILE_HEIGHT;

            // Check for vertical boundary
            if (displacedTile.y >= TOTAL_HEIGHT) {
              displacedTile.y = 0;
            }
          }

          newTiles[occupiedIndex] = displacedTile;

          // Add the displaced tile to the check queue
          tilesToCheck.push(displacedTile);
        }
      } while (occupiedIndex !== -1);
    }

    return newTiles;
  };
```

Pan responder:

```
  const panResponder = useMemo(
    () =>
      PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
          const newX = initialPan.x + gestureState.dx;
          const newY = initialPan.y + gestureState.dy;
          pan.setValue({ x: newX, y: newY });
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
          const finalX = initialPan.x + gestureState.dx;
          const finalY = initialPan.y + gestureState.dy;
          const closestSnapPoint = findClosestSnapPoint(
            finalX,
            finalY,
            snapPoints
          );

          let newTiles = [...tiles]; // Clone the tiles array
          const movedTileIndex = newTiles.findIndex(t => t.key === tile.key);
          let movedTile = { ...newTiles[movedTileIndex], x: closestSnapPoint.x, y: closestSnapPoint.y };
          newTiles[movedTileIndex] = movedTile;
          newTiles = handleChainReaction(newTiles, movedTile);

          checkGroups(newTiles);

          // Animate to the closest snap point
          Animated.spring(pan, {
            toValue: { x: closestSnapPoint.x, y: closestSnapPoint.y },
            useNativeDriver: false,
            friction: 30,
            tension: 60,
          }).start();

          // Update the initial position for the next drag
          initialPan.x = closestSnapPoint.x;
          initialPan.y = closestSnapPoint.y;
        },
      }),
    [tiles]
  );
```

Snaps:

```
    for (let row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < 16; col++) {
        const x = col * TILE_WIDTH;
        const y = row * TILE_HEIGHT;
        snaps.push({ x, y });
      }
    }
```

Example tile object:

```
{"color": "blue", "groupIndex": 0, "groupLength": 0, "isInGroup": false, "key": "n13-cblue", "label": 13, "number": 13, "x": 576.675, "y": 53.823}
```